# Given a Matrix that is Invertible What Does this Tell you About the Dimension of the Null Space?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
Given:
A=\pmatrix{5/4&3/4\\3/4&3/4}
$$
$$
Given: Inverse(A)=\pmatrix{2&-2\\-2&10/3}
$$
Since the above matrix has an inverse, what does this show about the dimension of the null space of the matrix? Also is the corresponding linear transformation one-to-one or not?

Comment: the null space is $\{0\}$

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of linear algebra?

Comment: @Ale: I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: @JHance sorry, you are right ;) edited it.

Comment: Yes, however the solution would be one-to-one though right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null space of a linear map $A : V \to W$ is the set of vectors $\boldsymbol x \in V$ such that $A\boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol 0$.  Since $\boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol 0$ always satisfies this condition, it is easy to see that the null space is never the empty set, but if the rank of the matrix $A$ is full--i.e., for a square matrix, if $A$ is invertible--then the null space has dimension $0$, and consists only of the zero vector as mentioned.

Comment: A map is injective (one-to-one) if for every element $\boldsymbol w$ in the codomain (here, the set $W$), there exists *at most* one element $\boldsymbol v \in V$ such that $A \boldsymbol v = \boldsymbol w$.  This is easily seen as violated if the null space is nontrivial, for then there would be at least two distinct vectors in the null space that map to the same element (the zero vector in $W$) in the codomain under $A$.